# For $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$, $f(x,y)=x-y$ is the function injective?

Tags: functions

> For $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$, $f(x,y)=x-y$ is the function injective?

I got this question in my homework and this is how I attempted to solve it:

> If I want to prove that a certain function $f:\,A\to B$ is injective, we need to show that
>
> *$a,b\in A, f(a)=f(b) \therefore a=b$*. So let there be arbitrary *$x,y,a,b$* so that *$f((x,y))=f((a,b))\implies x-y=a-b$*, from here I should somehow prove (if the function is injective) that *$x=a, b=y$*

But now I'm facing a problem and I'm not sure what to do now or if I have already solved the question: there are infinitely many pairs of *$a,b\in\mathbb N$* that result in *$a-b\in\mathbb Z$*

I tried using WolframAlpha but it couldn't answer my question, so I'm asking for help with my proof. What do I do now? Did I finish and I'm too blind to see it?

Comment: You have correctly argued that $f$ is **not** injective. For good measure, you can write a concrete counter-example: $f(2,1) = f(3,2)$ but $(2,1) \neq (3,2)$.

Comment: Hint. Try thinking in words about the meaning of the formula. Can you find two different pairs of integers that are the same distance apart?

Comment: I want to thank everyone! thank you for answering!